Fractional Sobolev embedding
Let $s\in (0,1)$ and $1<p<\infty$. Let $H^{s,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)=H^{s,p}$ the Bessel potential space, defined as the image of $L^p(\mathbb{R^n})$ by the Bessel potential. It is known that these spaces con be obtained by complex interpolation means by $$[L^p,W^{1,p}]_s=H^{s,p}(\mathbb{R}^n),$$ so I'm trying to prove all the known well facts about these spaces via only interpolation. In particular im trying to prove the sobolev embedding $$H^{s,p}\subset L^{p_s^*},$$ where $$p_s^*=\frac{np}{n-sp},$$ whenever $sp<n$. To prove it im using the interpolation propertie that states that if $T:E_0+E_1\to F_0+F_1$ is a bounded linear operator from $E_0 \to F_0$ and $E_1\to F_1$, then $T$ is a bounded linear operator from $[E_0,E_1]_s\to [F_0,F_1]_s$. To use this we have to differenciate cases for the value $p$. I have proved the cases $p\leq n$, so im interested in $sp<n$ and $p>n$. My idea is to define $$I:L^p+W^{1,p}\to L^p+C^{0,1-n/p};u\mapsto u,$$ since $W^{1,p}\subset C^{0,1-n/p}$ by the Morrey embedding. Now interpolating we have that $I$ is an inclusion operator from $H^{s,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ to $$[L^p,C^{0,1-n/p}]_s,$$ and since both spaces could be seen as Morrey-Campanato spaces, $L^p=\mathcal{L}^{p,0}$ and $C^{0,1-n/p}=\mathcal{L}^{p,p}$, we have the embedding $$[L^p,C^{0,1-n/p}]_s\subset \mathcal{L}^{p,sp},$$ so $$H^{s,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)\subset \mathcal{L}^{p,sp}(\mathbb{R}^n),$$ however that's not what i want. Is there any form of relating the space $\mathcal{L}^{p,sp}$ with $L^{p_s^*}(\mathbb{R}^n)?$ Or maybe a more suitable choice of the endpoints for the interpolation? Any idea will be very appreciated. Thanks in advance

In order to follow your approach, you can actually identify interpolation spaces between Lebesgue and Hoelder spaces to be a certain type of Triebel-Lizorkin space (see this paper by Triebel himself) and then use embeddings for these if you like.

The idea of the work is not to use Triebel-Lizorkin and Besov spaces

I see. Is it allowed to use the case $p>n$ and $sp>n$? This would give you the result up to $p_s^*$ by "elementary" means (reiteration).

Yes, since I managed to prove that case (which is Morrey fractional embedding) by means of Morrey-Campanato spaces and their relationship with Holder spaces

Okay, then, as I said, you can get the embedding of the interpolation space $H^{s,p}$ into $L^q$ for any $q < p_s^*$ by direct and elementary interpolation means, but I have no clue how to get the endpoint itself. In any case, the Morrey-Campanato embedding that you mention seems to be true. I am not an expert in this at all but a quick google search gave this where e.g. Theorems 0.0.12 and 0.0.14 seem to state what you want.

Yeah, that would answer my question. However, the result holds for bounded domains $\Omega$, maybe could be extended for the whole $\mathbb{R}^n$?
